# strtok problems on different versions of Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, types, char

When I change the Xcode I'm using to program in C the behavior of the following code changes with the same input data:

```
    char * aux = strtok (message,Utilities::Constants::SERIALIZATION_SEPARATOR);
    int i=0;

    while (aux != NULL)
    {
        splitedData[i]=aux;
        i++;
        aux = strtok (NULL,Utilities::Constants::SERIALIZATION_SEPARATOR);
    }
```

So In Xcode 5 it actually gives back the splitted string but in Xcode 4.2 it doesn't. I believe it should has something to do with the charset but I really do not know. 
message is char * and it is a parameter of the function on which this code is embedded.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your input, and what does your output look like?

Comment: 12%-1%9 and I want to split it by the %

Comment: are you getting any compiler warnings on either version?  The main difference I can imagine would be the actual compiler being used, XCode moved from gcc to llvm.  Both SHOULD work though, that is why Im asking about compiler warnings.

Comment: Well both are being compiled with llvm 5 and 3, I was thinking it might be the datatype.. bc I'm sending a char * instead of a char[], maybe the compiler does not recognize it as an array... I dunno know!

Comment: How do you know it's not working (are you setting a breakpoint)?  What is `splitedData` and how big is it?  I believe `strtok()` will work fine under Xcode 4.2 and 5, so it's likely something else in your code.

Comment: So I checked with a breakpoint, and is not entering to the while loop.. is like the compiler instead of understanding the data as an array it treats it like a single  character.. so instead of seeing 12%-1%9\0 it only sees 1\0... does it make sense?